# How to set the hostname of a postfix mail server?

Tags: postfix

In a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I have installed postfix. The domain name is `example.com`, the VPS hostname is `server.example.com`. For the domain `example.com` I create an MX record. After that a mail server `mail.example.com` is up and running.

How to in postfix configuration `main.cf` set `myhostname`?

```
myhostname=server.example.com
```

OR

```
myhostname=mail.example.com
```

Comment: `myorigin = $mydomain` will use the `dnsdomainname` of the system which should be your example.com domain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hostname is really the name of your VPS host. The name in your MX record goes into mydomain.

```
myhostname=server.example.com
mydomain=mail.example.com # if you receive emails as me@mail.example.com, or mydomain=example.com if you receive emails as me@example.com
```